A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function
I have been following a machine-learning book by Chollet and I keep getting this error in this block of code, specifically in the 3rd line. It seems I am passing a Keras tensor into a tf function but I don't know how to get around this.
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64")
embedded = tf.one_hot(inputs, depth=max_tokens)
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32))(embedded)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()

I tried to follow the solution in the error message which told me to create a new class but didn't know how to do it.

Wrap the TensorFlow function (tf.one_hot) in a layer. And, replace the call to the function with a call to the new layer.
eg:
class EmbeddedLayer(keras.Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return tf.one_hot(x, depth=max_tokens)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64")
embedded = EmbeddedLayer()(inputs)
x = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32))(embedded)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(
    optimizer="rmsprop",
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
model.summary()


Ohh thank you, that's what the error message told me to do but I couldn't figure out how.
